# Task.Run inside backgroundservice unexpectedly stops working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am using Task.Run inside backgroundservice. I have backgroundservice which is responsible for LogOn and Send HeartBeat for a specific system.

```
public class TestBGService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ITestService _testService;
    private bool MustLogOn { get; set; } = true;
    private string id { get; set; }
    public TestBGService(ITestService testService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Log.Information("TestBGService starts Initialize");
            await Initialize();
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            if (MustLogOn)
            {
                Log.Information("TestBGService ExecuteAsync trying to LogOnAsync");
                id = await _testService.LogOnAsync();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                {
                    Log.Information($"new id equals to {id}");
                    MustLogOn = false;

                    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                     {
                         while (true)
                         {
                             bool res = await SendHeartBeat(id);
                             Log.Information($"res from SendHeartBeat {res}");
                             if (!res)
                             {
                                 break;
                             }
                             await Task.Delay(10000);
                         }
                     });
                    await _testService.StartProcessAsync(id);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"TestBGService ExecuteAsync throws {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }


    private async Task<bool> SendHeartBeat(string id)
    {
        bool isSuccess = true;
        try
        {
            Log.Information("TestBGService sending heartbeat at " + DateTime.Now);
            var response = new HeartBeatResponseModel();
            response = await _testService.SendHeartBeatAsync(id);
            Log.Information("TestBGService heartbeat response equals to " + response.IsSuccessful);
            if (!response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                MustLogOn = true;
                isSuccess = response.IsSuccessful;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "TestBGService SendHeartBeat throws");
            isSuccess = false;
            MustLogOn = true;
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }

}
```

Initialize method trying LogOn to system and in the success case, it needs to start to SendHeartBeat. SendHeartBeat method is responsible for getting success or failure. In case of success, I am changing the value of MustLogon to false and sending SendHeartBeat every 10 seconds. Parallel for SendHeartBeat I need to call `_testService.StartProcessAsync` to get data from the stream. Somehow it stops working and it starts LogOn again but I need that until it returns false it should work and SendHeartBeat needs to be done every 10 seconds but unfortunately, it stops working in case of bool `res = true` and this moment it does not throw any exceptions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at this example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks and try to modify your code accordingly. You are not supposed to hang around in StartAsync method forever.

Comment: Fildor, it stops when I send cancellationToken

Comment: Note: `StopAsync` is doing nothing. It must do something like `cts.Cancel()` for `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: The main problem is that discarding Task.Run unexpectedly stops working and it affects to whole workflow

Comment: _discarding Task.Run unexpectedly stops working_ Are you sure that there's no Exception thrown inside of the loop? Wrap the loop with `try-catch` with logging and check.

Comment: Yes, because this is rubbish (sorry). Please do have a look on how a timed service is supposed to work (see link in first comment). In the Timer Callback: 1. Login if needed, 2. SendHeartBeat. Done. Don't start tasks from within tasks ...

Comment: Or you can just quick an dirty use `BackgroundService` from link @Fildor provided, moving your "`Initialize`" logic into `ExecuteAsync` (and removing `Task.Run` what is the point of it here?).

Comment: When Login returns success I need immediately start SendHeartBeat to keep the session alive and when SendHeartBeat starts it should send a request every 10 seconds until getting false and at the moment when I get false from testService.SendHeartBeatAsync(id) I am changing MustLogOn true coz I've done LogOff at the other side

Comment: It should restart after getting false from SendHeartBeat

Comment: There is literally nothing that stops you from doing that.

Comment: The reason it's not working **is because you are doing it wrong**. This is a problem that can only be solved by restructuring your code to work as Microsoft suggests. If you don't want to do that, you need to deal with your code not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with following the link from [BackgroundService base class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class) and "plug in" your required functionality: (untested, of course)

```
public class TestBGService : BackGroundService
{
    // I guess you are using different logging
    private readonly ILogger<TestBGService> _logger; 
    // Your service to send Heartbeats to
    private readonly ITestService _testService;
    // If id is null, we need to login.
    private string _id = null;

    public TestBGService (ILogger<TestBGService> logger, ITestService testService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _testService = testService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testService));
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("TestBGService  running.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // This will be triggered by the runtime.
    private async Task ExecuteAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while( !stoppingToken.CancellationRequested )
        {
            try
            {
                if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(_id) )
                { 
                     // _id is null => perform login
                     _id = await _testService.LogOnAsync(); // perhaps pass stoppingToken?
                }
                bool res = await SendHeartBeat(id); // again: consider passing stoppingToken
                if( !res ) _id = null; // Heartbeat unsuccessful: login next time
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), stoppingToken);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) // You should actually catch more specific exceptions.
            {
                // TODO log Exception
                _id = null; // Reset id, so we login next time.
            }

        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> SendHeartBeat(string id)
    {
        // Don't even try if login was unsuccessful.
        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ) return false;

        _logger.LogInformation("TestBGService sending heartbeat at {0}" , DateTime.Now);
        var response = await _testService.SendHeartBeatAsync(id);
        _logger.LogInformation("TestBGService heartbeat response {0}successful", response.IsSuccessful ? "" : "un");
        return response.IsSuccessful;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("TestBGService  is stopping.");
        // TODO maybe explicit logout?
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```